# Script to automatically grow LVM partition CentOS

Tags: centos6, lvm

I'm looking for a script to check the size of a particular LVM volume on CentOS 6.5 and when it reaches a certain threshold, have it automatically extend the partition and online re-size the file system.

I have this particular machine monitored, and could do it manually, but I saw a script once to do just this.

I have plenty of disk space on the physical volumes but, since it's easier to expand when needed than reduce later, I'd rather expand my logical partitions only when they start to fill up.  There are several logical volumes on this machine, but only one that regularly grows.

Any tips are appreciated; and, if the overall best thing to do is just expand the volume manually when the time comes that advice is welcome as well!

Comment: Use `df` to see the percentage usage of the file system. Use `lvresize` to increase the logical volume associated with the file system. Finally, use `resize2fs` to increase the file system to fit in the newly resized logical volume.

Comment: Yes, yes.  What I was wondering was if anyone had a script that would find the size of, say, dev/vg/lv_var and if it was over, again let's say, 90% then would run the lvresize on /var and do an online resize of the file system.  Or, am I just better off doing it manually when needed?  Use cases would be setting something like this up before an extended vacation, where the /var partition might fill up in the meantime.